# How to simplify property access in nested classes without strings

Tags: c#, properties, extension-methods, simplify

First of all please suggest a better title if necessary as I can't think of an accurate one. I was wondering if there was a way to simplify an access to a property that looks like this:

```
ClassA.SealedClassA.InternalClassA.ReadonlyPropertyA1;
```

Where `SealedClassA` is an inner class of `ClassA` and `InternalClassA` is an inner class of `SealedClassA`.

Lets say I have 1000 properties like this, all accessible in the same way from `ClassA`, and I want to use 200 of them, for example. I also cannot modify `ClassA`.

Is there any way I could code something that'd let me access those that'd be more convenient than having 200 times that "long" line of code without using strings ? The only ways I know right now are either to use the whole sequence or to use reflection and strings. The problem with strings is that if the property name changes, the reflection fails.

I'm thinking something along the lines of (this doesn't work obviously, but something with only a single call):

```
ClassA.ReadonlyPropertyA1();
```

Which would be some kind of extension method. Is that doable and if not, why ?

Comment: Make extension methods?

Comment: I wouldn't want to make 1000 extension methods though.

Comment: This is totally confusing.  What is the type of `ClassA.SealedClassA`, for example?  I'm struggling to see the overall picture of what you're doing here...are you dealing with composition here?  Your `ClassA` intstance has a `SealedClassA` property...what's its type?  And that type has a `InternalClassA` property...what is the type of *that*.  And the same for `ReadOnlyPropertyA1`.

Comment: It's an inner class, so its type would be SealedClassA. I see how that would be confusing sorry, will specify in the question.

Comment: Oh nested classes?  You didn't say that to begin with.  People's default assumptions aren't that you're using nested classes, and over-using them is probably not a good idea.  You should consider completely re-designing to get away from that.

Comment: Yeah my bad ! Also I can't modify `ClassA` as mentionned. It's not my code. If what I'd like to do is impossible then so be it, I'd just like to know why.